# How do I add column-specific plotlines using High Charts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make a column chart using js HighCharts that has 2 unique plotlines for each column of the chart, rather than a single plotline that spans the width of the entire chart.

This way I will be able to show a max and min value for EACH column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an actual plot line that works that way.

You can use a scatter series, and define a custom line marker type, like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/e96yX/

example code for both a horizontal line and a vertical line:

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.vline = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
};
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.hline = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + height / 2,'L',x+width,y + width / 2];
};
```

alternatively, based on your question, a column range chart may be helpful as well:

http://highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Comment: thanks.. is there a way to do that same thing but vertical instead of horizontal?

Comment: look in the code provided in my answer - there's one for horizontal, one for vertical

Comment: I am able to work with this but can't figure out how to apply it to a vertical graph / aka column layout / do you have a jsfiddle that shows it in vertical form? Thanks!

Comment: Okay actually I got it working on a vertical/column version. Can you please explain what that above code does? I am trying to make the scatterplot lines wider. Thanks!

Comment: Got it! Here is the JS Fiddle for what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/e96yX/7/    Thanks!

Comment: the code in my answer creates the marker type, and tells how to draw it.  It will use the radius property to determine how wide or how high, lineWidth to determine how thick, and lineColor to determine what color.   Are you all set?

Comment: My only remaining question is that since my containing divs are close together to mimic 1 single chart, the tooltips get cut off if they are wider than the containing div. I've been playing for 2 hours with z-index and overflow: visible to try and fix it with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: The original example was setup specifically to produce bullet graphs, which needed to be separate charts because I used plotBands to set the variable background shading.  If you don't need that aspect, there's no reason not to put these columns in a single chart where the tooltip won't be an isssue.